# Are Elasticsearch Security API authenticate responses the same for different logged-in users?

Tags: elasticsearch, plugins, kibana

My goal is to retrieve information about logged-in users in my custom kibana plugin, and for that, I'm using the https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/security-api-authenticate.html API. However, when I log in with different users, all values such as username, roles, etc., are coming out the same. Could I have made a mistake in configuring Kibana?

This is the function;

```
const user = await clusterClient.asInternalUser.security.authenticate();
```